# Fix a div after scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll

I would like to fix the div#order in this page http://www.spiaggiati.it/antani/ with this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#order").data("top", $("#order").offset().top);
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv("order"));
})
```

The function fixDiv is:

```
function fixDiv(div_id) {
    var $div = $("#"+div_id);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $div.data("top")) { 
        $div.css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}); 
    }
    else {
        $div.css({'position': 'static', 'top': 'auto', 'width': '100%'});
    }
}
```

I cannot make it work, it seems that scroll() is not catching the event. Where is it wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing a function as a reference you cannot supply a parameter. Try changing this:

```
$(window).scroll(fixDiv("order"));
```

To this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    fixDiv("order"));
});
```

Comment: another question: do you know how to make it work with mobile devices? This code is executed only when the scroll bar stops and the result is not nice.

Comment: I don't have a great deal of recent experience with mobile browsers. You're probably best to start a new question for that.